# .net 4 client to .net 3.5 server wcf issues

Tags: .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Is there any reason why one would see performance issues when connecting a .net4 web app to a .net3.5 windows service over net.tcp ?

The issues tend to appear during heavy load where the client is unable to make connections to the service, downgrading the client to .net3.5 seems to alleviate this problem.

Comment: Can you post some code? Same client code both ways, just a different target framework?

Comment: Yep, same code both ways, all we did was recompile under the different frameworks

Comment: How are you communicating with the service? Add service reference? ChannelFactory? Roll your own ClientBase implementation?

Comment: We are creating a proxy pool using a service reference

Answer (score 0):

Something to try would be to change the client implementation, I suspect that might be your issue. Use a [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) implementation instead of the Add Service Reference, which is a good idea no matter what.

You can encapsulate all of the ChannelFactory behavior if you would like so that it behaves the same way that the generated clients object behave if you want. If done correctly, there should be very little code to change on the clients.

Also, it doesn't sound like you have complete concrete evidence that downgrading DOES solve your problem. Consider performance metrics to zero in on the problem.